# Access to 2D array with another array

Tags: javascript

I have a 2D array and want to access with another array e.g:

```
var arr = [['one','two'],['three','four']];
var arr2 = [1,1];
```

I want to have the value at arr[arr2[0]][arr2[1]]. Is there another way to get the value, because if I do it that way, the row would get extrem long and hard to read.

Something like:

```
arr[arr2]
```

I know that this don't work but is there something similar in JavaScript?

Comment: Why don't you use a loop in `arr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reduce` with `try/catch` to ensure that doesn't have values which will throw error (for example, `arr2 = [1,1,2,3,4]` )

```
function evaluate(arr1, arr2)
{
    try
    {
      return arr2.reduce( (a, c) => a[c], arr);
    }
    catch(e) {}
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function evaluate(arr1, arr2) {
  try {
    return arr2.reduce((a, c) => a[c], arr)
  } catch (e) {}
}

var arr = [['one','two'],['three','four']];
var arr2 = [1,1];

console.log(evaluate(arr, arr2))
```

Comment: that solution uses an `try ... catch` concept for exception, which is not necessary for the task.

Comment: @NinaScholz You are right, yours is simpler. Since you had already posted that so I didn't changed mine.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array by using the indices, with a default array for not existent inner arrays.

```js
function getValue(array, indices) {
    return indices.reduce((a, i) => (a || [])[i], array);
}

var array = [['one', 'two'], ['three', 'four']],
    indices = [1, 1];

console.log(getValue(array, indices));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `arr[arr2[0]][arr2[1]]` instead of `arr[arr2]`. Since, you only have two array values in your nested array for `arr` you can specify the index `0` and `1` for `arr2` as a index of `arr`. Which is in the format `arr[index1][index2]`

```js
var arr = [['one','two'],['three','four']];
var arr2 = [1,1];

console.log(arr[arr2[0]][arr2[1]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on `arr2` and pass `arr` as the initial array.

**Demo**

```js
let arr = [['one','two'],['three','four']],
    arr2 = [1,1],
    res = arr2.reduce((a,c) => a[c], arr);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is an alternative:**

*A simple `for-loop`*

```js
var arr = [ ['one', 'two'], ['three', 'four'] ],
    indexes = [1, 1];

Array.prototype.getFrom = function(indexes) {
  var current;
  for (var index of indexes) current = current ? current[index] : this[index];
  return current;
}

console.log(arr.getFrom(indexes));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/egomezr/pen/dmLLwP.js"></script>
```